# gghighlight (R): Labeling bar charts

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-text, gghighlight

Alright, after a long silent read along, here's my first question. I am trying to add corresponding labels of unhighlighted items for a grouped barplot. When I insert gghighlight in front of the geom_text I get the following plot:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gghighlight)


df <- data.frame (group = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C"),
                  value  = c("value_1", "value_2","value_1", "value_2","value_1", "value_2"),
                  mean = c(1.331, 1.931, 3.231, 3.331, 4.631, 3.331)
)

ggplot(data = df, aes(x = group, y = mean, fill = value)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
  gghighlight(group != "B",
              label_key = group
              ) +
  geom_text(aes(label = round(mean, digits = 2)), 
            stat= "identity", 
            vjust = -.5,
            position = position_dodge(width = .9)
            )
```

[image: Bar chart with only highlighted labels]

If I move gghightlight behind the geom_text I get the following plot:

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = group, y = mean, fill = value)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
  geom_text(aes(label = round(mean, digits = 2)), 
            stat= "identity", 
            vjust = -.5,
            position = position_dodge(width = .9)
            ) +
  gghighlight(group != "B",
              label_key = group)
```

[image: Bar chart with double labels: highligthed and unhighligthed]

Is there a way to label the unhighligthed bars like the highlighted ones?

Thanks in advance.

############## EDIT ###########

Besides graying out certain columns (see @TarJae's answer), there is also the possibility to make them transparent (essential parts are from this post: [ggplot transparency on individual bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28979622/ggplot-transparency-on-individual-bar)):

```
subset_df <- df %>% 
  mutate(alpha.adj = as.factor(ifelse(group != "B", 1, 0.6)))


ggplot(data = subset_df, aes(x = group, y = mean, fill = value, alpha=factor(alpha.adj))) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
  geom_text(aes(label = round(mean, digits = 2)), 
            stat= "identity", 
            vjust = -.5,
            position = position_dodge(width = .9)
  ) +
  scale_alpha_manual(values = c("0.6"=0.6, "1"=1), guide='none')
```

[[image: Bar chart with transparent bars and labels]]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a solution with the `gghighlight` package and some limited *hacky* code.

When reading the vignette, I noticed that the author of the package "filters out" the data that are not highlighted. You can see that if you save your highlighted plot in `p_h` and then look at `p_h$data`, the values for group B have disappeared.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gghighlight)

p_h <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x = group, y = mean, fill = value)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
  gghighlight(group != "B",
              label_key = group) +
  geom_text(aes(label = round(mean, digits = 2)), 
            stat= "identity", 
            vjust = -.5,
            position = position_dodge(width = .9)) 

> p_h$data
  group   value  mean
1     A value_1 1.331
2     A value_2 1.931
5     C value_1 4.631
6     C value_2 3.331
```

If we re-insert the data (after the call to `gghighlight()` has removed them), then `geom_text()` will be able to find **the means for group B** again.

One can "recover" the data and re-insert them with the following code:

```
### create a ggplot object with the original complete data
### you could check that with p_to_copy_data$data
p_to_copy_data <- ggplot(data = df)

### copy the complete data to your highlighted plot data section
p_h$data <- p_to_copy_data$data
p_h
```

This yields the following graph:

[image]

Comment: Dear KoenV,

thank you very much for your quick help and diving into the depths of gghighlight. Your solution within the package is exactly what I originally was looking for. With the possibilities of TarJae and the addition in the original question, quite a few possibilities should now be covered. Great.

Answer (score 3):

Are you looking for this?
This is a solution without using `gghighlight` package:

```
library(tidyverse)

subset_df <- df %>% 
  mutate(highlight = if_else(group != "B", mean, NA_real_))

ggplot(data = subset_df, aes(x = group, y = mean, group=value)) +
  geom_col(fill = 'grey', alpha = 0.6, position = 'dodge') +
  geom_col(aes(y = highlight, fill = value), position = 'dodge') +
  geom_text(aes(group, label = round(mean, digits = 2)),
            position = position_dodge(width = 1))
```

[image]

Comment: Dear TarJae,
thank you very much for your super fast guidance. Indeed, your code is a very neat way where even more customization is possible. So I got some inspiration from you, and came up with one option for a transparent instead of gray coloring. See edit above.